# I have to add RealFontSizes dropdown in the RadEditor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I have a RadEditor where I need to add RealFontSizes dropdown and it should have values like (12px , 13px and so on). How do I do this in asp.net?
I have spent lot of time in this but didn't achieve the solution any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrY2j.png) 
this image shows how my dropdown looks

Comment: [Rad Editor](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) has this feature by default.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have achieved this but the problem is ByDefalut the value in RealFontSize dropdown is 16px, My first value is 11px in dropdown I want to make this default.

Comment: Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't get you, which one you want by default? 11 or 16?

Comment: MY first value is 11px so I want to make that By default. Now what is happening is in my RealFontSize dropdown I have value like 11px to 21px, but in the dropdown the value shows by defalut is 16px. I need to make that as 11px.

Comment: How do I make 11px as a defult value for RealFontSizes dropdown as 11px is the first value of the dropdown? Please help me with this

Comment: Have tried to set style property on rad editor. Like `style="font-size:11px;"` in rad editor tag.

Comment: Yes,I tried this but this didn't work for me. when first the page is loaded and when I see the rad Editor the value 16px  is shown, How can i make my first value as 11px as default in the fontsize dropdown

Comment: For some reason 16px is only the default value, and I have no idea how to make 11px as my first value. I have added image how it looks like , could you please help me with this

Comment: Did you set `ContentAreaMode="div"`

Comment: Can you show your markup code?

Comment: <telerik:EditorTool Name="RealFontSize" ShortCut="CTRL+SHIFT+P" />           <RealFontSizes>
                    <telerik:EditorRealFontSize Value="11px" />
                    <telerik:EditorRealFontSize Value="12px" />
                    <telerik:EditorRealFontSize Value="13px" />
                    <telerik:EditorRealFontSize Value="14px" />
                    <telerik:EditorRealFontSize Value="15px" />
                    <telerik:EditorRealFontSize Value="16px" />
                    <telerik:EditorRealFontSize Value="17px" /></RealFontSizes>

Comment: Now I am able to get 11px as my first value but when I am saving the changes of the Rad Editor and when I again open it the font sizes for other text are also 11px no matter what I have set it changes to 11px, How can I save whatever font I have specified

Comment: I solved this issue. Thanks for replying

Comment: Sorry bro i was busy. Glad to know that you have fixed.